# copy File form external Storage folder into the same folder with different file extension

Tags: android, copy, rename, external

I want do copy a file from external storage into the same folder but with different file extension.
It works doing it on internal SD card:

**works**: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Test.txt -> /storage/emulated/0/Music/Test.log

**don't work**: /storage/3339-6133/Test/Test.txt -> /storage/3339-6133/Test/Test.log

Permission where set, seems that this isn't the problem.

```
Log.d(TAG, "copyRename...path 1: "+path);
path = path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
Log.d(TAG, "copyRename...path 2: "+path);
String destName = name.substring(0,name.length()-4)+".log";
Log.d(TAG, "copyRename...destName: "+destName);

File from = new File(path,name);
File to = new File(path,destName);

boolean rC = from.renameTo(to);
Log.d(TAG, "copyRename...rename done: "+rC);
```

Logcat for internal and external:

```
MainActivity: copyRename...name: Test.txt
MainActivity: copyRename...path 1: /storage/emulated/0/Music/Test.txt
MainActivity: copyRename...path 2: /storage/emulated/0/Music/
MainActivity: copyRename...destName: Test.log
MainActivity: copyRename...rename done: true

MainActivity: copyRename...name: Test.txt
MainActivity: copyRename...path 1: /storage/3339-6133/Test/Test.txt
MainActivity: copyRename...path 2: /storage/3339-6133/Test/
MainActivity: copyRename...destName: Test.log
MainActivity: copyRename...rename done: false
```

Can anyone give me a hint whats to do?

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: A removable micro sd card is read only since Android Kitkat. You only have full access to one app specific directory on it.

Comment: So put your file in that app specific directory under Windows. For the path have a look at the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: @blackapps: That's it. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

do you have permission to write to this folder `/storage/3339-6133/`? `/emulated/0/` is external storage card, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is sufficient for this path, but this `/storage/3339-6133/Test/` folder seems to be somewhere in system permission, usual apps won't ever have access to this path

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is set. I copy the file in this folder using windows explorer and get tha path using `ContentProvider Query`. Got the same result, when trying to copy from folder`/storage/3339-6133/Storage Card/Test/`. this folder is the external Device Storage Card.